# Opening gMail Website to a specific message

Tags: gmail-api

I'm using the gMail Node API to search for specific messages (not drafts) using the gmail.users.messages.list API, then I use the gmail.users.messages.get API to get the details for the message.

So I have the message id, thread id etc.... in the payloads returned. I present the user with the subject line from each message and I would like to also give the user a URL that will open the message in the gMail website.

If I use the gMail website to open one of the messages that are in my test bed the URL for gMail is:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/3/#inbox/FMfcgzGljlhhRnrLbTDqXnNxSbhRcVCN

I could easily put that URL together myself but here are my questions:

1. Will the '/u/3/#inbox' portion of the URL always be the same for the authenticated user?
2. How do I get the ID at the end of the URL(beginning with FMfcgz...)? I searched the payloads from the API's and I cannot find that ID in any of the data returned.